# How can we add a source file from .Net Core project in a .NET project?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a little problem ! I have two projects, one on .Net Core and one on .Net.
I need to use some source file from the .Net core project but I can't add a reference to this project because of the framework version.

Is it possible to add a reference to my files without copying them in the project ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to the `netstandard` documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

for example, if you target the `netstandard1.3` you can use your `.NET Core` library on the .NET Framework 4.6 and above.

Try to lower down your netstandard version of the .NET Core project to be compatible with you .NET Framework project.

> In general, we recommend you to target the lowest version of .NET
> Standard possible. So, after you find the highest .NET Standard
> version you can target, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Target the next lower version of .NET Standard and build your project.
> 2. If your project builds successfully, repeat step 1. Otherwise, retarget to the next higher version and that's the version you should use.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! I will try to use my project with Framework 4.6.1 avec tooling 2 !